# What channel initiation threshold value should I use when creating a stream network for drainage density calculation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, watershed

I need to calculate drainage density for two southern AL watersheds (D’Olive and Fly Creek).

What channel initiation threshold value should I use when creating the stream network?

I am following these instructions http://gis4geomorphology.com/watershed/ to create my stream network and will calculate drainage density using this http://gis4geomorphology.com/drainage-density/ calculation.

Comment: I'd say average watershed size of upstream point for permanent streams in the region

Comment: Thanks for the input. Could you please elaborate a bit? Do you mean average watershed area?

Comment: Pick few points at the start of 'official' streams, i.e. ones shown on the best map. Snap to nearest cell high flow accumulation. Sample above raster at points, take average